# Updating uitableview datasource and updating tabbar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbar

I need your advice.

I have a screen with a table view and I'm using a separate file for `UITableViewDataSource`.
What I need is to be able to access the `UITabBarItem` inside my `UITableViewDataSource` (because based on the action on my tableview, I will update my tableview data, so I need to change something on my tabbar)

Any idea ?

Thanks.

To separate my datasource, in my controller I have:

```
    var toPayDatasource: MyDataSource!
....
        tableView.dataSource = mDatasource
        tableView.delegate = myDatasource
```

And my datasource:

```
class MyDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
...
}
```

C.C.

Comment: Is it necessary to have your data source separated from the view controller?

Comment: Do you want the data source to change `UITabBarItem`? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @Bojan: I prefer having my datasource separated to have my code cleaner and easier to read

Comment: @Gasim: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @CC. Are you using an `extension` to separate the datasource?

Comment: I just updated with the datasource part.

Comment: @CC. Consider using extensions of the original view controller to conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate ` protocols. Then you will have direct access to your view controller. https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#protocol-conformance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common mechanism for sending a message between two objects that are otherwise far apart is to use [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html).  You can define a custom event and pass along whatever you need to update the tab bar item in the `userInfo` dictionary.

Comment: I did knew about NotificationCenter. I've looked about it, and it's pretty nice. I will use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your datasource is separate you can create a Delegate for the view controller and pass it to the data source. Something like the following (right after setting data source for the tableView):

```
mDataSource.tabDelegate = self;
```

And declare / define the delegate the following way:

```
// protocol
protocol TabChangerProtocol {
   // function signatures here
}

// data source
class MyDataSource : /* ... */ {
    var tabDelegate : TabChangerProtocol!;
    // rest here 
}

// view controller
class ViewController : TabChangerProtocol, /* ... */ {
// ...
}
```

That way you can call the protocol functions from inside MyDataSource.

P.S Sorry for all the 3 dots. Typing code on mobile is annoying.